# Java: How to programmatically select and expand multiple nodes in a JTree?

Tags: java, swing, select, jtree, treenode

I have a `JTree` and an `awt.Canvas`. When i select multiple objects from within the `Canvas` into the `objList`, I want all the selected items to be shown inside the `JTree` as selected. That means for example if I have 2 objects selected, both their paths to root should be expanded, and also each selected object should have its corresponding `TreeNode` selected. My JTree has `TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION`.

Here is a sample of the expand funcion i use :

```
public void selectTreeNodes() {


    HashMap <String, MyEntity> entities = ...;
    Iterator it = entities.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {

        String str = it.next().toString();
        MyEntity ent = entities.get(str);

        if (ent.isSelected()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode searchNode = searchNode(ent.getName());
            if (searchNode != null) {

                TreeNode[] nodes = ((DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel()).getPathToRoot(searchNode);
                TreePath tpath = new TreePath(nodes);
                tree.scrollPathToVisible(tpath);
                tree.setSelectionPath(tpath);
            }
        }
    }
}

public DefaultMutableTreeNode searchNode(String nodeStr) 
{ 
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = null; 

    Enumeration enumeration= root.breadthFirstEnumeration(); 
    while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {

        node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)enumeration.nextElement(); 
        if(nodeStr.equals(node.getUserObject().toString())) {

            return node;                          
        } 
    } 

    //tree node with string node found return null 
    return null; 
}
```

In my current state, if I select a single object, it will be selected in the `JTree` and its `TreePath` will be shown.
But if `entities` has more than 1 object selected, it will display nothing, my `JTree` will remain unchanged.

Comment: *"I have a `JTree` and an `awt.Canvas`."* Don't mix Swing with AWT components.  The `Canvas` should be a `JPanel` or an image displayed in a `JLabel`.

Comment: I know I shouldn't usually do that (I have some problems with the main menu expanding behind the canvas), but in this case the only connection between them is the array of entities from the canvas that are represented in the tree. And in the GUI there is some space between them, so no harm is done/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for the `TreeSelectionModel` of the `JTree` (use the getter). Use the [`TreeSelectionModel#setSelectionPaths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeSelectionModel.html#setSelectionPaths%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath%5B%5D%29) for multiple paths. Now you are only setting one node selected due to your `tree.setSelectionPath(tpath);` call. The `TreeSelectionModel` also has methods to add/remove to an existing selection ,... (basically everything you might need in the future).

An interesting method for the expansion is the [`JTree#setExpandsSelectedPaths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setExpandsSelectedPaths%28boolean%29) method which allows to configure the `JTree` to automatically expand selected paths. If you want to manage this manually, you can use the [`JTree#setExpandedState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setExpandedState%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath,%20boolean%29) method